# Can remote debugging Visual Studio 2010 use breakpoint, watches and step into?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, remote-debugging

Currently I debug my C# application locally and use watch, breakpoint and commands like step into and the debug inspector.

setup remote debugging with another machine as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx

Is it possible to see the source code of remote application and go through it step-by-step as one can do locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Attaching to a remote process is just the same as attaching to a local process.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.  Just make sure that your symbol files (your .PDB files) are deployed remotely with your application.

Comment: Thanks, same answer from both of you.